# Centering flexible width content with css

Tags: css, positioning, inline

I am having difficulty trying to horizontally center an (inline?) element within my containing div.  I want "some text" to have a background which collapses to it, and for that all to be centered within the containing element.  I know I can do this if i specify a width, but I am trying to avoid that

Check out a simple example I put together with some nonworking css...
JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mqw5R/ (works great even without js!)

```
<div>
<p>Some text</p>
</div>

=========================
=                       =
=      |some text|      =
=                       =
=========================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `text-align:center` to the *containing* element, not the child, like so:
http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/Mqw5R/1/

Comment: I wonder how long that would have taken me to figure out by myself

Comment: @Zach L. :-) been there before.  don't forget to mark as answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: It made me wait 15 minutes I think or I would have immediately.  Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/Mqw5R/3/

Why don't you just put

```
text-align:center;
```

Inside of your DIV css?